# Jasmine/Karma test services with params

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine

I want to test with Jasmine & Karma a service dependency with TestBed or SpyOn. But I didn't find any example on Angular site how I can do it: https://angular.io/guide/testing

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a minimal example on how to get started with testing services.  Under most circumstances you won't need to use the TestBed, so I left that out of this minimal unit test example:

Abc service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class AbcService {

  constructor(private otherService) {
  }

  add(x: number, y: number) {
    return x + y;
  }

  submit(x) {
    this.otherService.submit(x);
  }

}
```

Abc service spec file:

```
import { AbcService } from './abc';


describe('AbcService', () => {

  it('should add 1 + 2', () => {
    // Arrange
    const sut = new AbcService(null);

    // Act
    const result = sut.add(1, 2);

    // Assert
    expect(result).toEqual(3);
  });

  it('should dispatch SET_INTERACTION when setAnswer is run', () => {

    // Arrange
    const mockOtherService = jasmine.createSpyObj('mockOtherService', ['submit']);
    const sut = new AbcService(mockOtherService);

    // Act
    sut.submit(10);

    // Assert
    expect(mockOtherService.submit).toHaveBeenCalledWith(10);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
describe('Test Service', () => {
    let yourCurrentService: YouCurrentService;
    let yourServiceDependencyService : YourServiceDependencyService;

    beforeEach(() => {

      let injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
        YouCurrentService,
        YourServiceDependencyService
      ]);
      yourCurrentService = injector.get(YourServiceDependencyService);
      yourCurrentService = injector.get(YouCurrentService);
    });

    it('test', () => {

    });  
});
```